# Amazon web services: upload scripts to cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am a new user of Amazon web services. I have used Rackspace for PHP hosting, and switching to Amazon is a bit confusing for me.

I have uploaded all my scripts to Amazon S3, but seems it is only used for storage.
I have created my database on Amazon RDS, seems fine to me.

**But i don't know where to upload my PHP scripts. I have read mostly about EC2. I have set up environment through SSH and created instances but where should I uploaded my program code??**

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 can only server static files. It has no ability to run php. In order for your php to run, one of your instances needs to have a webserver installed and running, probably apache.

You need to look at your instances and see which one has apache installed. It will ned to have a public IP address assigned to it in order for the outside world to be able to reach it.

If you are using apache, then you need to find out where it has been configured to serve your site from. Mine is configured to use /var/www, and this is defined in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

in a setting called DocumentRoot.

Comment: EC2 provides me with ip address and also has apache installed but i can't figure out where to upload my code?

Comment: If you have ssh access you can upload files via scp. If your files are in version control, you can also check them out on your instance.

Comment: Updated my answer to help find where apache needs the files.

Answer (score 0):

See if **/var/www/html/** exists, and if so, put the files in there. That would be your default DocumentRoot in many cases and PHP will execute with your Apache web server so long as you have a PHP interpreter with a module for Apache installed. You will likely use an SFTP or SCP client to upload the files, but most likely you will have to upload first to your 'regular user' (e.g. not root) and then move them, and set permissions for the web server user (probably apache or www).

If you detail which AMI you are using and/or what Linux distro you have deployed, this could be easier.